# Displaying images stored in AWS S3 with a presigned URL in my react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I followed the steps outlined here: https://ademcan.net/blog/2017/11/24/uploaddownload-images-tofrom-aws-s3-in-react-native-a-step-by-step-guide/ with a focus on step 5.2 to successfully get my node.js/express server to fetch a presigned URL for an image I stored in S3.

I include this url in my response packet to my React Native client. In the client, I would like to display the image using this presigned URL. Am I thinking about this correctly? But the image does not display. I am stuck on what I must change about my react native code to get the image to display.

Here is my Node.js code for fetching a presigned URL and adding this value to the user object in the response to mu client...

```
// Retrieve all Users from the database.
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => {
  const title = req.query.title;
  var condition = firstname ? { firstname: { [Op.like]: `%${firstname}%` } } : null;
  try {
    let data = await User.findAll({ where: condition });

    /* The 'data' object is immutable, so we need to create a new object
    'updatedData' that can hold additional parameters such as presignedURL.
     */
    let updatedData = []; 

    // get a presigned url for each user's profile image.
    // Note that the profile_image value contains the name of the file
    // in the S3 bucket. 
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var params = {
        Bucket: "surfnomad",
        Key: "users/" + data[i].profile_image,
      };
      let url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("getObject", params);
      updatedData.push({ ...data[i].dataValues, presignedURL: url });
    }
    res.send(updatedData);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users.",
    });
  }
};
```

Here is my React Native code where I try to use this presigned URL to fetch the images from S3 and display them in the app screen...

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://192.168.100.33:8082/api/`,
});
class Sandbox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    api
      .get('/users/')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error fetching users: ' + error);
      });
  }
  renderUsers() {
    let users = [];
    console.log('this.state.users: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++) {
      users.push(
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.users[i].firstname}</Text>
          <Image
            style={{ width: '50%', height: '50%' }}
            source={{ uri: this.state.users[i].presignedURL }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return <View>{users}</View>;
  }
  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderUsers()}</View>;
  }
```

I confirmed that this.state.user[i].presignedURL contains the presigned URL we generated in the node.js code. But the image will not display. And if I change the url to the url for an image that is publicly available on the internet, that image displays just fine. So, there is an issue using this presigned URL to fetch the image from S3.

Comment: Test the node function alone locally and `console.log` the url. Then copy-paste it into a browser. What error do you get?  Check for misspellings/undefined in the key.  Note that the SDK will create a URL even if you have mistyped something.  It just won't work.

Comment: This is correct. I had set the region incorrectly. After changing to "us-east-2", which is my S3 account's region, the images appeared as desired.